# What is the format of a Helium API "B58" address?

Tags: helium-api

The [Helium API](https://docs.helium.com/api/) includes several requests that specify an address in "B58" format ([examples](https://docs.helium.com/api/blockchain/accounts/)).

What is the "B58" format, and what API will return a B58 address given a Helium node name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the "B58" format

It is sort of like base64 encoding, but some easily confused characters have been removed from the alphabet. From [wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-to-text_encoding#Base58)

> Similar to Base64, but modified to avoid both non-alphanumeric
> characters (+ and /) and letters that might look ambiguous when
> printed (0 – zero, I – capital i, O – capital o and l – lower-case L).
> Base58 is used to represent bitcoin addresses.[2] Some messaging and
> social media systems break lines on non-alphanumeric strings. This is
> avoided by not using URI reserved characters such as +. For segwit it
> was replaced by Bech32, see below.

> and what API will return a B58 address given a Helium node name?

You want: https://api.helium.io/v1/hotspots/name/:name
From here: https://docs.helium.com/api/blockchain/hotspots/#hotspots-for-name

I think it was added sort of recently, so it likely didn't exist when you asked this question.

Comment: Just in case anybody sees this in a Google Search - The address returned in a hotspot search is the Wallet ID associated with the hotspot and NOT the B58 address.

Comment: The B58 address can be found by doing a hotspot search: https://api.helium.io/v1/hotspots/name/my-awesome-hotspot. It's the value of owner. Once you have owner you can get the wallet balance from https://api.helium.io/v1/accounts/{MYB58ADDRESS}.

Comment: >  The address returned in a hotspot search is the Wallet ID associated with the hotspot and NOT the B58 address
@user3063045, are you sure? This URL: `https://api.helium.io/v1/hotspots/name/raspy-hazelnut-raccoon`
returns JSON that has an `"address": "11Q2DyYDanPuUi8KHmiZUDRbsf7UXtbE36FNEY63nMDs5PobRN1"` key/value pair. That address is the b58 address of the hotspot, isn't it?